# How do I create array of JButtons in java?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton

I just wanted to create a TicTacToe game in java in eclipse. It has been about a month and I still can't get how can i create array of JButtons with 3*3 grid. I have tried watching lots of tutorial, tried it myself too.

It would be helpful if someone would provide me the code to create 3*3 grid JButton.

Answer (score 1):

Here is i think what you are searching :

```
package so1;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;

public class MyWindow extends JFrame {

    public MyWindow() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        int maxWidth = 3;
        int maxHeight = 3;
        JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[maxWidth][maxHeight];
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(maxWidth, maxHeight));
        for (int i = 0; i < maxWidth; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < maxHeight; j++) {
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton(i + "," + j);
                panel.add(buttons[i][j], maxWidth * i + j);
            }
        }
        setContentPane(panel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyWindow ex = new MyWindow();
        ex.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I just know how to add actionlistener to i and j int created in for loop.

Comment: *"It would be helpful if someone would provide me the code.."* SO is not a code generation service. *"Can I just know how to add actionlistener"* It's also not a help desk. In future, please don't ask for code, and ask each question on a separate question thread. This helps everybody, including the people that come later, looking for solutions to specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][3];
```

Answer (score 0):

`JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][3];`

To assighn value to `button[0][0]`, you have to do this:

```
buttons[0][0] = new JButton();
```